# Does weapon quality degrade overtime?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I have a "minimal wear" p90 "Sand Spray"(or something like that) and I have a good amount of "field tested" skins. Over time in my inventory, does item quality degrade(while unequipped) or do the items have to be actually used to get beat up?

Comment: Please comment why the downvote! there is no reason to downvote!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No the skin exterior quality does not degrade. It will always stay the same.

> Note also that a weapon will not degrade over time; a weapon skin will
>   stay in that state forever.

<sub>from [CS:GO Wikia](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Skins)</sub>

Comment: Downvoter explain please!!